# What's the difference between normal folder and application in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, windows, directory, virtual-directory, iis-10

I'm setting up an IIS site, and want to support many different Sub-ENVs in one site. What should I do about IIS structure? An application within a normal folder or using sub application?

Directory Structure:

```
D:\MySite
|_qa1
  |_app
|_qa2
  |_app
```

One method:

```
MySite
|_qa1(normal folder)
  |_app(application)
|_qa2(normal folder)
  |_app(application)
```

Another method:

```
MySite
|_qa1(application)
  |_app(application)
|_qa2(application)
  |_app(application)
```

App pool

```
MySite: MySite
qa1: MySite_qa1
app in qa1: MySite_qa1_app
qa2: MySite_qa2
app in qa2: MySite_qa2_app
```

I read the doc [Virtual Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory). But it is said that you might use a virtual directory when you want your application to include images from another location in the file system, but you do not want to move the image files into the physical directory that is mapped to the application's root virtual directory. It is different from normal folder.

So what's the better choice? And could you describe the advantage or disadvantage?

Answer (score 0):

> What's the difference between normal folder and application in IIS?

In my opinion, the main difference between the normal folder and application in IIS is the application will have its own application pool, but the folder don't.

The folder will inheit from its parent IIS's websites application pool.

> I'm setting up an IIS site, and want to support many different Sub-ENVs in one site.

In my opinion, choosing which method is according to your actual requirement.

If qa1 or qa2 is just a folder which contains different apps, I suggest you could set its as a folder not a application, since become a application will have its own application pool, which will take system resource to run it.

If qa1 or qa2 is just a folder which contains its own application file, I suggest you could set its as a application, since it could be managed by different application pool.

Comment: It's the same app, may different version. I don't understand 'its own application file'.
'qa1' and 'qa2' are to separate the two different ENVs. Actually, it's not an application. There will be two URLs, as 'site.com/qa1/app' and 'site.com/qa2/app'

Comment: As you said, application will take system resource to run it. But what if it uses the same app pool with its site or its sub-application?

Comment: If you use same app pool, it will only use run one w3wp.exe(IIS worker process). That means you couldn't set the different ENV for different site. Each application pool will run a w3wp.exe(IIS worker process). If you want to set the folder as application, you should assain a application pool for that folder qa1. Then you will assain another application pool for the qa1's app.

Comment: You said 'If qa1 or qa2 is just a folder which contains different apps, I suggest you could set its as a folder not a application, since become a application will have its own application pool, which will take system resource to run it.'

If qa1 is application using the pool MySite, does this qa1 app take extra system resource?

My goal is to get the difference from normal folder and application. If using application is graceful practice, I'll convert the folder to application. 

So do you have some ideas about this?  I would be very grateful.

Comment: You should understand the application contains the application pool which will create a w3wp.exe to run the application but the folder doesn't. Using application pool may take more resource than using folder.

Comment: Static Site VS Dynamic Site, got it. Thanks